# be questioned of, be asked of

Tags: prepositions

> 1. I was questioned of my validity of being there with my child in surgery.
> 2. I was questioned of who I was.
> 3. I was asked of my job history and provided a detailed description.

I've come across the sentences on the internet.
I'm not sure whether they sound natural or not.
I think that "of" isn't the correct preposition in those sentences and it should be changed with "on" or "about" because they doesn't make sense if re-written as below

> 4. He questioned me of my validity of being there with my child in surgery.
> 5. He questioned me of who I was.
> 6. He asked me of my job history and provided a detailed description.

Comment: None of the sentences sound natural, nor are they grammatical. Your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 2):

> I was questioned about the events.

"About" is a preferable choice. That is ok.

> I was questioned of the events.

Incorrect. "Of" is a grammatical error.

> I was questioned on the events.

This sounds *somewhat* incorrect... It depends. "On" can be used on a case by case basis.  Imagine a headline: "Senator questioned on policy".  That's alright.  It really means "about the policy".

So, generally the word should be "about".

Comment: Are you a native speaker of English? To you, do the original sentences not only make no sense but also sound very unnatural? But somewhat interestingly I've just been told by a native speaker 1st and 2nd sentences sound natural to his ears. I just want to confirm this again.

Comment: @SIS , yes native speaker. "questioned of" sounds incorrect.  However, there may be certain turns of phrase, where it can make sense... There are always counter-examples to everything.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm still confused because there are some people telling me the sentences can make sense. What I've in mind is that they seem to make sense at least but just are not the usual ways to say. I want to conclude which one is correct.  1) they make sense, but just not the usual way to say so. 2) they don't make sense and not the usual way to say so.

Comment: @SIS , they "make sense" when read. That's because you can almost ignore the preposition. It doesn't interfere with understanding. Many ungrammatical sentences make sense, and you can figure them out.  Even with a misspelling, a missing word, an extra word, the wrong word, etc.   So, there's a difference between "make sense", and "correct."

Comment: Thank you for your help!, anyways, the confusing is way more provoked by those telling me they sound natural. it would be not the problem, if they were just saying "make sense".

Comment: Is the reason they are not grammatically correct and sound unnatural be well explained by showing the unnaturalness of my re-written sentences?

Comment: @SIS , it's not always necessary to rewrite a sentence in order to show that it sounds unnatural.  Sure, sometimes that helps.  In this case, as a commenter added, "None of the sentences sound natural"

Answer (score 0):

Questioned about or questioned on are the correct ones but often is is used without preposition at all, [see for example here](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/questioned)